# Extract whitespace-collapsed text from html as it would be rendered

Tags: html, html-parsing, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I use an html parser (Neko) in order to extract the free-text of an html document.
Since I'm interested in text's semantic I must give special attention to the distance between words as it appears in browser.

for example:

```
<H1>My
title</H1>
<P>Hello
                World</P>
```

Is rendered as:

```
My title
Hello world
```

While containing the paragraph inside `<pre>` tags or with style:

```
<style>
p { white-space:pre; }
</style>
```

would result:

```
My title
Hello
                    World
```

which I would like to treat differently since "Hello" for that matter is not semantically tied to the word "World". As said in other posts - there's a difference between what parsing does and what rendering does. I'm interested in the connection between words as it appears after rendering since obviously parsing doesn't collapse white-spaces as would been shown on browser.

Is there any way to extract whitespace-collapsed text from html as it's read on browser?

Comment: Try pre-wrap or pre-line if that isn't working properly it's not the problem of the pre option but with loading your css or seomthing

Comment: Thanks, But what I want is to extract `Hello World` and `Hello[ Spaces               ]World` from html code according to how it's shown on browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used Neko before, but you will need to access the styles of the elements and see if the `white-space` property is set to either `pre`, `pre-wrap`, or preline.

1. If it is either `pre` or `pre-wrap`, replace any whitespace group in the text with a single space.
2. Else if `pre-line`, only replace groups of spaces/tabs with a single space.
3. Else, do not modify the text.

Here's an example using JQuery: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueVyd/1/)

**JQuery**

```
function getRenderedText(obj) {
    var text = obj.text();
    var renderedText;
    switch (obj.css('white-space')) {
        case 'pre':
        case 'pre-wrap':
            renderedText = text;
            break;
        case 'pre-line':
            renderedText = text.replace(/[ \t]+/,' ');
            break;
        default:
            renderedText = text.replace(/\s+/,' ');
    }
    return renderedText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks For pushing me to the right direction. I really hoped I won't need to access styles or look for <pre> tags and collapse whitespaces on applied elements - I searched a lot for something simpler but I see now there's no way out of it. So my first step is to parse style blocks with some css parser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this basic info on w3schools

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

and a bit better explained with examples:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

i also think that you have to put hello in 1 `<p>` and world in another for the effect to work.
otherwise they both go to the right.

Comment: Sorry. I guess I wasn't so clear. My question wasn't about me as an html editor trying to get the browser to show the text as I want. What I'm actually trying to do is to take an html file and parse it in order to extract the text as it's shown on browser (with consecutive spaces or not according to the different cases)

Comment: Hm. allright. i think i don't get it quite right. but there's another answer above me. see if that's what you're searching for :)